# Nginx: If static file not found, try the same URL on webserver

Tags: nginx, configuration, uwsgi, nginx-config

I'm running a server that serves map tiles, by default from the `/var/www/tiles` directory. If a tile file is not found, I want nginx to try the `tiles` path on the uwsgi server like this: `/tiles/9-250-250.png` - the uwsgi app is setup to generate tiles dynamically and will return a file on that path.

This is the current nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www;

        location /tiles/ {
        }

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/home/one/wikiscape/wikiscape.sock;
        }
}
```

What do I need to add to the `location /tiles/ {}` directive to redirect (?) to the server if the file is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be sufficient to add `try_files $uri /$uri;`

```
location /tiles/ {
        try_files $uri /$uri;
}
```